# How to let Odroid wait untill RTSP stream is active

Tags: bash, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, rtsp

I want to show a live video of a local camera on a monitor trough a RTSP stream which is streamed on VLC. The setup is as follows:

- Hikvision IP camera
- Switch
- Ordroid

The Hikvision and Odroid have both a static ip address.

It's important that the stream auto start when both devices are booting up at the same moment.

Currently I've the following bash script:

startvideo.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
  /usr/bin/cvlc -vvv -f 'rtsp://'
  sleep 5
done
```

Give it permission to execute:

`chmod +x startvideo.sh`

In Ubuntu I've added the script to the autostart list.

The stream is working fine if the Odroid boots when the camera is already active. The problem occurs when the camera and the odroid are booting up at the same moment. I think that the odroid is booting up quicker than the camera, so when the odroid is booted the script will fail because it can't find the camera.

I was trying to add a sleep before the while loop starts, but that's not working.

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 180

while true; do
  /usr/bin/cvlc -vvv -f 'rtsp://'
  sleep 5
done
```

I've also tried to ping the ip to check if the camera is active.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; 
do
    if ping -c1 ip &> /dev/null
    then
        /usr/bin/cvlc -vvv -f 'rtsp://'
        sleep 5
        break;
    else
        echo 'ip not active'
    fi
    sleep 3 
done
```

Comment: Maybe you could add a test if the *camera* is already on/active/booted before executing your `cvlc` instead of using arbitrary `sleep` value?

Comment: @Jetchisel I've tried that with pinging the ip address. I've added the code i used in the question.

Comment: A loop maybe? `until ping -c1 $ip &>/dev/null; do printf '%s\r' waiting...; sleep 5; done`, Add a timer? a limit? and then execute your `cvlc` maybe?